# Angular 2 table row validation

Tags: angular, validation, primeng-datatable

I'm try to do table row and I'm getting an error saying property 'errors' is undefined or null. Name.errors is blowing up. Any ideas on what I'm missing. See my code below.  Got idea from [Angular 2 table row control validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847220/angular-2-table-row-control-validation/46733202#46733202)

Thanks

```
 <form >
  <p-dataTable [value]="data"  [editable]="true" [style]="{'whitespace': 'nowrap'}">
   <p-column field="Name" header="Name*" [sortable]="true" >
                <ng-template let-col let-rowVal="rowData" pTemplate="body" let-ri="rowIndex" >
                    <div style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px">
                        <span *ngIf="!rowVal.isEditing" class="editable-text">{{rowVal.Name}} </span>
                        <input type="text" *ngIf="rowVal.isEditing" [(ngModel)]="data[ri].Name" #Name="ngModel"  [value]="rowVal.Name"  name="Name{{ri}}" [pattern]="validName" required />
                        <div *ngIf="Name.errors != null && Name.errors?.pattern && rowVal.isEditing"><span style='color:#ff3a20'>Required</span></div>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
        </form>
```

Comment: try `*ngIf="Name?.errors`

Comment: It seems that Name is always null, which is the problem.  Adding the ? makes the errors go away but the validation never fires off.